# RMarkdown - running the current chunk pollutes the global environment

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Frequently, in RStudio, in  a markdown file, I find myself doing command-shift-enter to run the current chunk.  This pollutes the global R environment.

Is there anyway I can create a 'current environment' or 'live environment' so that anything that gets run in the console gets attached to that environment and not to the global one?

Comment: Probably best  asked at http://community.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no, but I don't see this as a problem.  You should be starting with a blank global environment every time (make sure you have "Save workspace to .RData on exit" to "Never" in the general global options).

It's a bad idea to rely on keeping variables in the global environment between sessions, because things gradually build up there, and you end up with non-reproducible results.